# Are there any foods usable by new characters?

Tags: guild-wars-2

When starting a new character, what food buff items are available? Or do all food buff items have a minimum level?

What food items are available for low level characters and what benefits do they bring?

Comment: Have you had a look at http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Food? Have you looked on the trading post, where you can add filters for level? Of course you can buy your low-level characters some food, or have your chef craft some, but typically, new players would be too poor for that, and experienced players would have scrolls/tomes to level new alts up past 20 anyway, wouldn't they?

Comment: Rather than a rude reply, why not simply answer the question. New players might find this information helpful to have on Arqade. Plus a new player won't have any experience scrolls. If you find the wiki page helpful, link it in your answer. What you know well isn't obvious to everyone else, remember that. Arqade is a resource for everyone, not just experts.

Comment: I certainly didn't mean to be rude, and I apologise if you felt I was, though I did want to point out that your question showed little or no research on your part. I know you've played the game for quite some time and have been around Arqade for much longer than I, so I honestly wouldn't have expected a question from you that the obvious first search ("food") on the obvious first resource (the wiki) could have revealed to any new player. I would respectfully ask you to take a step back and take another look at your question.

Comment: A brief search would have given you your answer.

Comment: The brief search may well have led to Arqade, where the solution can be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of low level food items available, from level 0, according to [the wiki page about food](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Food).

However most food buff items start becoming more plentiful and powerful as the level of the item increases.

Although all food items will provide a small bonus to experience as well.

[Filtering food items by level on GW2DB](http://www.gw2db.com/items/consumables/food?sort=requiredlevel) also produces a list of consumable items.